efficiently group list of index/value pairs to list or dict of lists
I have a long list of (i, j, value) pairs, with multiple values for each position, the number of values varies for each position.
At the moment I am initializing an empty "3d" list with
sorted = numpy.empty((m, n, 0)).tolist()

then I loop over each entry in the array and append the value to the list at i, j.
for pixel in value_list:
    sorted[pixel[0]][pixel[1]].append(pixel[2])

This is slow and hard to parallelize since I have to write to the same lists and don´t know how long they are going to be at the end.
I think my problem is very similar to
the defaultdict Example for  grouping a sequence of key-value pairs into a dictionary of lists, where the key would be "i,j".
Is there a more efficient solution to this or maybe something that is easily paralellized?

How large is m, n? How many values are there in average/max for each m, n combination?

m, n is 11 by 11. the index/value list can be quite large, up to 1.6E9 entries.

I was going to suggest the defaultdict approach,  but you edited the question before I could post.  Not sure it would be any faster, but seems like it might use less memory.
from collections import defaultdict
pixel_values = defaultdict(list)

pixel_list = [
  (1, 2, 42),
  (2, 1, 43),
  (1, 2, 44),
  (3, 4, 45)
]

for pixel in pixel_list:
  x, y, value = pixel
  pixel_values[(x, y)].append(value) 
print(pixel_values)


yeah, sorry for the quick edit, I was just finished writing when I found out that the defaultdict example almost exactly described my problem in a much more concise way.
I have also found
itertools.groupby()
which can be called by key and could be combined with multiprocesssing I guess. I am not sure about the speed gains tough.
